# MongoDB database design for products and bundles

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to build an e-commerce website based on Node.js with a mongoDB database and I am encountering problems about some database design or some logic I am missing

To sum up, I have `Product` that contain price, name, description etc... and `Bundle` that contains an array of products (by reference). The main problem come when I have to order, I can't get `Product` AND `Bundle` together ...

So I have already a `Product` schema :

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  file: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  preparation: String,
  allergics: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  // More fields
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

And a `Bundle` schema that contains ref to `Product` (A bundle contains multiple products) :

```
const bundleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  itemsId: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Product',
    required: true,
  }],
  description: String,
  reduction: {
    type: Number,
    min: 0,
    default: 0,
    max: 100,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Bundle', bundleSchema);
```

So when a user orders a bundle OR a single product, I use this schema :

```
const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  orderedBy: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
  articlesId: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Product',
    },
  ],
  itemsNumber: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
  },
  amount: Number,
  orderedAt: Date,
  placeToShip: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Place',
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
```

As you can see, I only reference to `Product` , but I want to reference to `Product` AND `Bundle` , I don't know if this is possible, or if this is the wrong way to design the database like that.

Sorry if the post is a bit long, but I am trying to be as clear as possible! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to reference `product` or `bundle`(depending on user buys bundle or single product) in `articleId`, you can do it like this:

Dont give `ref` in the `articleId` field of your `orderSchema`, just specify its `type` as `ObjectId`.

```
const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  articlesId: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
    },
  ],
  ...
});
```

And, while populating tell it which `model` to `populate` from.

```
//In case user bought a product
Order.find({findQuery})
     .populate({path : '',model : 'Product'})
     .exec(function(err,result){...});

//In case user bought a Bundle
Order.find({findQuery})
     .populate({path : '',model : 'Bundle'})
     .exec(function(err,result){...});
```

But, you must have a way to find out `user` bought a single `product` or a `bundle`.
Hope that helps you!

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, I will try this tonight, keeping you updated on the thing!